# Can't observe containers in google/cadvisor

Tags: docker, cadvisor

When I click on Docker Containers link, I get this message:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on
>   this host?

I user linux containers on Windows 10

**docker version:**

```
Client:
 Version:      17.06.2-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   cec0b72
 Built:        Tue Sep  5 19:57:19 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.2-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   cec0b72
 Built:        Tue Sep  5 19:59:19 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Comment: How did you run the setup of cadvisor?

Comment: Seems like the container is missing the docker.sock ( volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro). How do you run the container?

Comment: from Kitematic, latest version .0.17.1.0

Comment: @kogoia you could try to run it as follow to see if it makes a difference: 

sudo docker run \
  --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
  --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw \
  --volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
  --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro \
  --volume=/dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro \
  --publish=8080:8080 \
  --detach=true \
  --name=cadvisor \
  google/cadvisor:latest

Comment: @Sergiu Can't use sudo, I use Docker on Windows

Comment: oh yes :) sorry about that, have you tried running the command without 'sudo' then? @kogoia

Comment: @Sergiu Yes, I run cmd as admin and receive this `docker run --volume=/:/rootfs:ro --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw --volume=/sys:/sys:ro --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro --volume=/dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro --publish=8080:8080 --detach=true --name=cadvisor google/cadvisor:latest
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid bind mount spec "/rootfs:ro": invalid volume specification: '/rootfs:ro'.
See 'docker run --help'.`

Comment: after researching a bit more I came across this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/34327 which makes believe that Cadvisor might not support Windows as of right now :(

Comment: @Sergiu, but I use linux containers on Windows. Docker daemon has own host machine and it run in Hyper-V as MobyLinuxVM.

Comment: As I know, Windows containers and Linux Containers are different things, but on Windows we can use Linux Containers with VirtualBox or Hyper-V. In this case, the Docker Daemon (server) run on Linux and the Docker Client (CLI) on Windows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154362/discussion-between-kogoia-and-sergiu).